# convert JSON string to array mono

Tags: c#, json, mono

I'm trying to convert a string with JSON data to an array.
I'm using `NewtonSoft.JSON`

The following line of code holds my JSON data in a string:

```
string jsonString = manage.getData();
```

I've tried the following:

```
name[] result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<name[]>(jsonString);
string name = result.Name;
```

Name class:

```
using System;

namespace Zoekfunctie {
    public class name {
        public string Name {get;set;}
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
}
```

So how can I convert my JSON string to an array of strings?

JSON string: `[{"id":"42","naam":"Bas Jansen"},{"id":"41","naam":"Bas Jansen"}]`

Comment: So you've tried something - and what happened? (I'd strongly advise using more conventional and meaningful names, by the way.) It's not clear whether the string is really a JSON array or not... but if it is, just use `DeserializeObject<name[]>` instead...

Comment: What does the JSON string look like?

Comment: @JonSkeet you're  absolutely right about the names. I edited it.

Comment: It doesn't help that your JSON doesn't match your class at all...

Comment: I've actually also got an iD field in my class but I didn't included it in my question. Edited it now.

Comment: And the naam/Name difference? (If you'd provided a short but complete example right from the start, all of this could have been avoided...)

Comment: naam is dutch for Name I should be more consistent with naming my variables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to call `DeserializeObject` providing the array type instead of the single class type. Here's a short but complete program demonstrating this... I've adjusted your JSON and class to match each other.

```
using System;
using System.IO;

using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class Person
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string text = "[{\"id\":\"42\",\"Name\":\"Bas Jansen\"},{\"id\":\"41\",\"Name\":\"Bas Jansen\"}]";
        var array = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Person[]>(text);
        Console.WriteLine(array.Length);
        Console.WriteLine(array[0].Id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so your JSON string is already an array.

If you are looking for an Array of Name class, then this is the first thing that springs to my mind.

```
List<Name> result = new List<Name>();
var tempArr = JArray.Parse(jsonString);

foreach(var item in tempArr){
    result.Add(new Name(){Name = item.naam})
}
```

You can then call `result.ToArray()` if you need an array and the list wont suffice.

If your name class represented the objects in your JSON fully (the ID field is missing) you could replace the line in the `foreach` with

```
result.Add(JsonConvert.Deserialize<Name>(item.ToString()));
```

As the to string method on a JToken (The type of elements within a JArray when it is parsed) returns the JSON string for the object.

Hope this is along the lines of what you are looking for.